# Modeling with differential and difference equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, mathematical-modeling

I'm a bit confused when trying to Modeling some real life problem using ODE as an example :
the population doubles every 1 year, we can express this situation using ODE as follows :
$$ \frac{dP}{dt} = 2P \implies P = P_0e^{2t}.$$
but in the real world this model is continuous, so the population won't be doubled each year.  As an example: let
$$P_0 = 10^4, \quad P(1) = 10^4e^2 > 2\times10^4 $$
so it becomes more realistic to model it using discrete time modeling using difference equation:
$$ 
a_n = 2a_{n-1} \quad \text{( Linear difference equation )}  \\ a_n = a^na_0+b\frac{1-a^n}{1-a},\qquad(a=2,b= 0,a_0=10^4)
\implies a_n=2^n\times10^4 
$$
which is more intuitive and realistic.  This is in one year, but if I needed to get the population within 4 months not 1 year which model is more accurate, and generally how to decide which method should I use to make a model for the situation differential equation or difference equation?

Answer (score 1):

Your premise is wrong, "the population doubles every 1 year" does not translate to

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=2P.$$

Let us assume that (time being expressed in years) after one year the population is multiplied by $m$, and let us ignore the pregnancy delay. The equation reads

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=aP,$$ with the solution

$$P(t)=P_0e^{at}.$$

Then

$$P_1=P_0e^a=mP_0$$ and $a=\log m$ so that

$$P(t)=P_0m^t.$$

Comment: Thanks for explaining, i got it, but when i tried using this method on other problem it didn't work, assume the population being doubled every year and $n$ persons die every year : 
$$ P_1e^a = mP_0 - n  \hspace{20pt} \Rightarrow \quad a = log(m-\frac{n}{P_0}) $$ but that is wrong because $P_0$ is a fixed value it works at $ t = 1 $ and if $t$ takes other value it won't work, why it doesn't work in this case?